# SQL (SpatiaLite) - Multiple multi-criteria left joins with data from a select query

Tags: sql, left-join, spatialite

What I want to do (see Image below for help):

1) create a list with unique keys from two lists

2) use that new list to select red sub-squares from the black area (think of the red square clusters as areas with their own area_key)

3) now join data from two tables (green and orange), to sub-squares; this needs three attributes to be unambiguous (area_key, id_1, id_2)

4) result: red squares, with sub-squares containing extra data, if present, all in one set

Note: area keys are not found in biglist; I have to connect biglist -(sar_id)- subareas -(area_id)- Areas, to get the info

My attempt so far..

This part works:

```
SELECT bl.item_id, bl.item_geometry, bl.id_1, bl.id_2, ar.area_key, ar.name
FROM biglist bl, subareas sar, areas ar
WHERE area_key IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT area_key 
FROM areas ar 
WHERE ar.area_key IN (SELECT area_key FROM sublist_1) 
OR ar.area_key IN (SELECT area_key FROM sublist_2))
AND sar.area_id = ar.area_id AND bl.sar_id = sar.sar_id
```

What I need to integrate (partially incorrect syntax!), but can't get right:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tb1.name, tb1.id_1, tb1.id_2, tb1.info1, tb1.info2, tb1.area_key
FROM Table1 tb1) ON ar.area_key = tb1.area_key 
AND bl.id_1 = tb1.id_1 AND bl.id_2 = tb1.id_2

LEFT JOIN (SELECT tb2.name,  tb2.id_1, tb2.id_2, tb2.info1, tb2.info2, tb2.area_key
FROM Table2 tb2) ON ar.area_key = tb2.area_key 
AND bl.id_1 = tb2.id_1 AND bl.id_2 = tb2.id_2
```

Image:
[image]